# Cannot find name 'JSON' typescript file

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have created an angular application where I am doing JSON conversion functionalities like JSON.stringify, JSON.parse I am getting error like Cannot find name 'JSON' and also I am getting error in tsconfig.json like below

Argument for '--lib' option must be: 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es7', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'esnext', 'dom', 'dom.iterable', 'webworker', 'scripthost', 'es2015.core', 'es2015.collection', 'es2015.generator', 'es2015.iterable', 'es2015.promise', 'es2015.proxy', 'es2015.reflect', 'es2015.symbol', 'es2015.symbol.wellknown', 'es2016.array.include', 'es2017.object', 'es2017.sharedmemory', 'es2017.string', 'es2017.intl', 'esnext.asynciterable'.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,    
    "target": "es2015",   
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
 Savesresponse(socialusers: Socialusers) {  
    this.SocialloginService.Savesresponse(socialusers).subscribe((res: any) => {  
      debugger;  
      console.log(res);  
      this.socialusers=res;  
      this.response = res.userDetail;  
      localStorage.setItem('socialusers', JSON.stringify( this.socialusers));  
      console.log(localStorage.setItem('socialusers', JSON.stringify(this.socialusers)));  
      this.router.navigate([`/Dashboard`]);  
    })  
  }
```

Comment: Looks like it's rejecting ES2018 and not getting to 'dom'. What version of typescript are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add es5 inside lib of compilerOptions

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What if OP wants ES2018?

Comment: @prince  ERROR in The target entry-point "angular-6-social-login" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/core
 - @angular/common
 - rxjs

Comment: Can you try changing it to esnext or es6 from es5